# Creating a client list table in meteor using tabular

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm working of the Base User admin project from:
https://github.com/themeteorchef/building-a-user-admin

I want to change the user list table to a dataTable using aldeed:tabular. I have the following in the users tempalete:

```
{{> tabular table=TabularTables.UsersAdmin selector=selector class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"}}
```

and in client/lib/userAdmin.js I added

```
Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

Template.users.rendered = function(){

TabularTables.UsersAdmin = new Tabular.Table({
name: "User List",
collection: Meteor.users,
pub:"users",
columns: [{data:"roles",title:"Role",
  render: function (val, type, doc) {
    return val[0];
  }},
{ 
  data: "emails",
  title: "Email",
  render: function (val, type, doc) {
    return val[0].address;
  }
}],
});

}
```

If I render the user page I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: TabularTables is not defined.
Error: You must pass Tabular.Table instance as the table attribute
at null.<anonymous> (tabular.js:119)
```

I thought the was some publish problem, However, if i type in the console:

```
Meteor.users.findOne().emails[0].address
Meteor.users.findOne().roles[0]
```

Both parameters returns the functions, so the variables are available to the Admin user. 
Any Ideas? Am I using tabular wrong?

Comment: I removed `Template.users.rendered = function()`  and did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error: 
The referencing and all was correct. Just forgot to include:

```
TabularTables = {};
```

At the top. Also the TabularTables code should be in a client and server space.

:-o and Yes. wasted too much time!